# Apache Tika parses AC3 file as application/octet-stream and not audio/ac3

Tags: java, apache, mime-types, apache-tika

Provide a AC3 audio file as input, fetch InputStream and pass it to Apache Tika.

While the library lists audio/ac3 in its mime types XML, it fails to identify the type. It works fine with the other standard media types.

Anyone know how to fix this.

```
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
metadata.add(Metadata.RESOURCE_NAME_KEY, fileName);    
TikaConfig config = TikaConfig.getDefaultConfig();
MimeTypes mimeTypes = config.getMimeRepository();
tikaMediaType = mimeTypes.detect(new BufferedInputStream(inputStream), metadata);
```

Comment: I guess Tika doesn't have the magic key for dolby digital. Weird.

Comment: What happens if you pass the Filename as well when you do the detection? Also, what version of Apache Tika are you using?

Comment: I am passing the filename too, in Metadata. (Updated the code above). The version I am using is 1.16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a newer version of Apache Tika!

Specifically, Apache Tika 2.0, or a nightly build / build from Github from 2017-12-24 or later.

The mime detection magic for AC3 and EAC3 files was only recently added, via [this commit to the project](https://github.com/apache/tika/commit/10cd2055b43c6983aa4e7d95da53680355f39bac)

Comment: Thank you Gagravarr. I just tried my tests with the JAR from the latest code on Github and it worked for me. Do you happen to know when the stable version 2.0 would be released?

Comment: @AbhishekNandgaonkar No date yet, and a few more breaking changes still need to be made!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar issue. An update to the newest version, as suggested by *@Gagravarr* in the currently accepted answer helped, but **did not** solve my issue eventually.

For me, a detection with `File` was working and returned `image/png`. With an `InputStream` it returned `application/octet-stream`.

I identified upon thorough debugging of Tika, that **the InputStream I was utilizing had been previously consumed by another function**. Consequently, the InputStream was already positioned at its end. Executing the `inputStream.reset()` function, to reset the InputStream to its start was ineffective.

To resolve this, I had to reload the InputStream **before** invoking the `tika.detect(inputStream)` function to ensure proper detection of the `Content-Type`.